# Using iter function inside next function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, iterator, iterable

When I use the following:

```
s = 'hello'
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    print next(iter(s))
```

The code just prints `h` five times.
But when:

```
s = 'hello'
s_iterable = iter(s)
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    print next(s_iterable)
```

All letters from `hello` are printed.

If in both cases `iter(s)` and `s_iterable` are iterator objects, why do they give me different results?

Comment: `for index in range(len(anything)):` is a mistake most of the time --- Python will do all that busywork for you.  Your loop could be as simple as `for char in string:  print char`.  See Ned Batchelder's "[Loop Like a Native](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html)" (30-minute [video from PyCon US 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o)) for easy ("Pythonic") ways to handle many cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one, you repeatedly call `iter` in your loop. When you call `iter(s)`, it makes a new iterator for the string, and that new iterator starts from the beginning. It doesn't make sense to start from the beginning again and again. That's why you only get `h`'s printed out.